# How in the earth my aplication is still running even when the appdelegate and main.m is missing

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I restore the apps from time machine.

The app run just fine.

However, when I check the project, my appDelegate is gone. I can't see the file in the editor. It becomes red.

[image]

What is going on?

The files are still in finder though.

Restarting xcode doesn't work. Removing and adding files is kind of risky, though I'll give it a try tomorrow.

[image]

Maybe xcode just "forget" where the file is. But I get my app compiled.
Note: The problem is solved. Restarting iMac works. It's one of those get fixed by it self eventually. However, if someone can explain why the hell this happened in the first place it'll be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those are good answer. I restarted iMac and things work fine.

I think this has happened several times. It's one of those fixed by itself problem eventually. This one it ticked me off that I asked question.

I still do not understand why it actually happens. So I'll wait for more people to answer this.[image]

Comment: +1 for all answers. However, what really solved it is simply to restart imac or wait a while.

Answer (score 1):

Check the target's Build Phases.  The files being compiled can be shown in Finder using a context menu.

Answer (score 1):

u can do a dirty move trick in deleting and re-adding ur file into Xcode. They'be correctly added into the build phase as well.
Deleting the reference is not risky because the references are lost. If you do a clean project, you may have a compiler build error.
U just has to drop again ur already added file into your Xcode project, but don't check "Copy items into destination group's folder" since your files are already included in your folder.

This happening to me lot of time when i'm using svn.